# Put variables in a buffer in different parts of the program

Tags: c, sockets, buffer

I'm currently working on a C project that requires me to send variables from on file to another through a socket connection (on the same machine - through "localhost"). Therefore, in order to send variables from file A to file B, I put such variables in a buffer (defined as a char 1D array) and send the whole buffer with the different variables contained in it. To do so, I use sprintf(buffer, "%f\n %f\n", variable1, variable2) to put the variables from File A. For File B to read the buffer, and associate the variables in the buffer to variables of it's own, I do:
sscanf(buffer, "%f\n %f\n, &variable1, &variable2); where variable1 and variable2 would have been defined in File B.

However, I'm wondering if it's possible to put variables in the buffer in File A through different instances in the program. If so, everytime a new variable is put in the buffer, will File B be able to access the variables in the same order they're put in file A? For example, if variable1 and variabe2 are put in the buffer in point A, and then varibale 3 is put in the buffer in point B, will File B be able to access those variables in that order?

Finally, if a variable of the same name is put in the buffer in two different locations, will the second time overwrite the first? I.e, if variable1 is put in the buffer in point x and then again in point y, will the second time the variable is put in point y overwrite the time it was put in point x?

I'm not sure if my question was clear enough but I hope it was and I appreciate any help!

Comment: Please post relevant part of your code along with your question

Comment: @ManuelSelva I have included the different functions that I use in my question but I'm not able to include them as code since I'm using an old version of Internet Explorer

Comment: Which OS are you targeting ?

Comment: @cnicutar I'm using a Linux OS

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can solve your problem using standard Unix IPC mechanisms. You don't give too many concrete details on what you want to achieve but it seems you could try something like:

- Make a semaphore (named or not) that processes share

  - Look for `sem_open`
- Make a data structure - maybe a queue - that lives completely in shared memory

  - Look for `shm_open` and `mmap`
- All operations on the queue should be protected by the semaphore

  - For example an `add` to your queue should be protected by a `sem_wait` / `sem_post` block